# Problem with sync between iPhone and Lotus Notes (using outlook connector)

Tags: itunes, iphone, sync, microsoft-outlook-2003, lotus-notes

iPhone : iOS 3.1.3
Lotus notes : 6.5 fr version

We used to setup a link between itunes (9.0.3.15 fr version) and Notes by using Outlook (office 2003 SP1 fr version).

I'm having trouble using the olconn2.exe from Microsoft (Outlook to Lotus connector, fr version).

This used to worked, but after a few weeks (this happened in july) the system simply stopped working. I'm not the end-user using this, but I did set it up originally.

When I use Outlook, the sync between outlook and Lotus works great. But when I try the sync in itunes, with outlook, I keep getting an error message :  "Vous ne pouvez pas démarrer Outlook Connector pour Domino. Vérifiez que le client Lotus Notes est installé et correctement configuré, déconnectez-vous, connectez-vous ensuite à votre ordinateur ou domaine, puis redémarrez Outlook Connector pour Domino." The english translation should be something like this : "The Domino Outlook Connector can't start. Verify that the lotus notes client is properly installed and configured, disconnect yourself, reconnect to the computer or domain, then restart the Domino Outlook Connector".

I guess the user might have installed something preventing the use of the connector.

I did reinstall everything already (Office, Lotus, itunes), so it shouldn't be an unwanted update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to solve my issue. Actually, on the the apple component was updated in the month of July. It wasn't "in itunes" directly.

So I uninstalled the following apps:

- Apple Application Support
- Apple Mobile Device Support
- Apple Software update
- iTunes
- QuickTime
- Microsoft Office Outlook Connector pour IBM Lotus Notes (fr)

Then reinstalled iTunes 9.0.3.15, QuickTime (separatly) 7.6.6 and the Outlook Connector.

I hope this help someone else!